# Apache reverse proxy of bokeh server not serving interactive content

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, bokeh

I have the interactive slider example, sliders.py, running locally on my server with no issues. However, when I try to use Apache 2.4.7 to set up a reverse proxy between `bokeh.example.blah` and `http://127.0.0.1:5006/sliders`, the page on a remote computer loads without the interactive element, although HTML elements like the page title do load.

I run sliders.py with this command
`bokeh serve sliders.py --host bokeh.example.blah`
A tornado 404 warning pops up when I try to access `bokeh.example.blah`:

```
    INFO:bokeh.command.subcommands.serve:Starting Bokeh server on port 5006 with applications at paths ['/sliders']
    DEBUG:bokeh.server.tornado:[pid 7611] 0 clients connected
    DEBUG:bokeh.server.tornado:[pid 7611]   /sliders has 0 sessions with 0 unused
    INFO:tornado.access:200 GET /sliders (127.0.0.1) 43.49ms
    WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /slidersstatic/css/bokeh.min.css?v=25ce17349a0082e9eeac845e42a822ec (127.0.0.1) 0.84ms
    WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /slidersstatic/css/bokeh-widgets.min.css?v=3b73ec63df304369ffc9c7e5132463cd (127.0.0.1) 0.78ms
    WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /slidersstatic/js/bokeh.min.js?v=50ffae624cbe67773b5995270f946406 (127.0.0.1) 0.69ms
    WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /slidersstatic/js/bokeh-widgets.min.js?v=7cfd458197bc395bb09e9dc3b8ac7975 (127.0.0.1) 0.71ms
    WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /slidersstatic/js/bokeh-compiler.min.js?v=28af56ac5027aa8d0ab96086ec1da10b (127.0.0.1) 0.74ms
```

I this is my `000-default.conf`

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyHTMLEnable On

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName bokeh.example.blah
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5006/sliders
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5006/sliders

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
```

Interestingly, no apache error log is created when this happens.

Googling tells me that serving dynamic content with apache through a reverse proxy is sometimes problematic- this led me to add the 'ProxyHTMLEnable On' to my .conf file. If anyone has seen this sort of issue before and has advice it would be much appreciated!

I also notice that there seem to be a few places that indicate that documnetation about how to deploy bokeh apps is pending. For instance, the empty Deploying for Production section [here](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/server.html#deploying-for-production), or this [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/3164). Does information about this already exist and I'm just looking in the wrong place?

Thanks!

### Update:

I now have a different error.

The previous error was due to the fact that I hadn't specified where bokeh keeps its static files. I did so by modifying '000-default.conf' to this:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>    
        ServerName bokeh.example.blah                                                                                     

        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass /sliders/ws ws://127.0.0.1:5100/sliders/ws
        ProxyPassReverse /sliders/ws ws://127.0.0.1:5100/sliders/ws

        ProxyPass /sliders http://127.0.0.1:5100/sliders/
        ProxyPassReverse /sliders http://127.0.0.1:5100/sliders/

        <Directory />
            Require all granted
            Options -Indexes
        </Directory>

        Alias /static /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/static
        <Directory /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bokeh/server/static>
            # directives to effect the static directory                         
            Options +Indexes
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

As before, I can load only the title of the HTML page, but not the interactive plot. Now, the java console gives me this error:

```
    WebSocket connection to 'ws://bokeh.example.blah/sliders/ws?bokeh-protocol-version=1.0&bokeh-session-id=pyrxrMepBAnQyAdl4UpACinDdhxcegz0SWtNnonrLngM' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
    bokeh.min.js?v=50ffae6…:62 Bokeh: Failed to connect to Bokeh server Error: Could not open websocket
```

I would really appreciate advice!

Comment: Take a look into your browsers development console. Check for JS errors and look through the network connections. Any errors?

Comment: There is detailed information about an Apache deployment in the current "development" version of the docs: http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/dev/docs/user_guide/server.html#apache

Comment: Ok these comments are really helpful. The development JS console displays a bunch of errors; mostly of the form:
'bokeh.example.blah/static/css/bokeh-widgets.min.css blah Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'
So it's confused because it's looking for a non-existent static folder. I notice in the apache server guide it says I should 'Alias /static /path/to/bokeh/server/static'
Where do I get these static files from though? I don't have any.